# XML Parsing in Java using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have successfully "loaded" an XML file to my java program using DOM. Is it possible to access this information now in a different function? I can print out the contents of XML file when I'm in the same function as the parser but how would I go about doing so in another function.

I'm trying to access the xml info from the searchMenu function using a search function in another class.

I'm not sure if I have the terminology correct so let me know if you need clarification.

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ListIterator;


public class XMLParser {
public static void adminMenu(String[] args) {
            if (args[1].equals("load")) {
                try
                {   String fileName = null;
            fileName = args[3];
                        File file = new File(fileName);
                        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = builder.parse(file);
                        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

                        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("hostel");

                        System.out.println("----------------------------");

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
                        {
                                Hostel hostel = new Hostel();
                                Node node = list.item(i);

                                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getNodeName());

                                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                                {
                                        Element element = (Element) node;


                                        hostel.setName(tagInfo(element,"name",i));
                                        System.out.println("HostelName : " + hostel.getName() );

                                        hostel.setStreet(tagInfo(element,"street",i));                                        
                                        System.out.println("Street : " + hostel.getStreet());

                                        hostel.setPhone(tagInfo(element,"phone",i));
                                        System.out.println("phone: " +hostel.getPhone());

                                        hostel.setCity(tagInfo(element,"city",i));
                                        System.out.println("City : "+hostel.getCity());

                                        hostel.setState(tagInfo(element,"state",i));
                                        System.out.println("State : "+hostel.getState());

                                        hostel.setPostalCode(tagInfo(element,"postal_code",i));
                                        System.out.println("Postal Code : " + hostel.getPostalCode());

                                        hostel.setCountry(tagInfo(element,"country",i));
                                        System.out.println("Country : " + hostel.getCountry());

                                        hostel.setEmail(tagInfo(element,"email",i));
                                        System.out.println("Email : " + hostel.getEmail());

                                        hostel.setFacebook(tagInfo(element,"facebook",i));
                                        System.out.println("Facebook : " + hostel.getFacebook());

                                        hostel.setWeb(tagInfo(element,"web",i));
                                        System.out.println("website : " + hostel.getWeb());

                                        hostel.setCheckin(tagInfo(element,"check_in_time",i));
                                        System.out.println("Checkin : " + hostel.getCheckin());

                                        hostel.setCheckOut(tagInfo(element,"check_out_time",i));
                                        System.out.println("Checkout : " + hostel.getCheckOut());

                                        hostel.setSmoking(tagInfo(element,"smoking",i));
                                        System.out.println("Smoking : " + hostel.getSmoking());

                                        hostel.setAlcohol(tagInfo(element,"alcohol",i));
                                        System.out.println("Alcohol : " + hostel.getAlcohol());

                                        hostel.setDeadline(Integer.parseInt(tagInfo(element,"cancellation_deadline",i)));
                                        System.out.println("Deadline : " + hostel.getDeadline());

                                        hostel.setPenalty(tagInfo(element,"cancellation_penalty",i));;
                                        System.out.println("Penalty : " + hostel.getPenalty());


                                        NodeList list2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("availability");
                                        for (int j = 0; j < list2.getLength(); j++)
                                        {
                                                Bedroom bedroom = new Bedroom();
                                                Node node2= list2.item(j);
                                                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node2.getNodeName());

                                                if (node2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                                                {
                                                        Element element2 = (Element) node;
                                                        bedroom.setDate(Integer.parseInt(tagInfo(element2,"date",j)));
                                                        System.out.println("date : " + bedroom.getDate() );
                                                        bedroom.setRoom(Integer.parseInt(tagInfo(element2,"room",j)));
                                                        System.out.println("room : " + bedroom.getRoom());
                                                        bedroom.setBed(Integer.parseInt(tagInfo(element2,"bed",j)));
                                                        System.out.println("bed : " + bedroom.getBed());
                                                        bedroom.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(tagInfo(element2,"price",j)));
                                                        System.out.println("price : " + bedroom.getPrice());
                                                }
                                                hostel.addBedroom(bedroom);
                                        }
                                }

                            //  hostel.availableSearch(20140704, 20140705);//remove later
                                //hostel.sortBedrooms();
                                //hostels.add(hostel);
                        }
                } catch (Exception e)
         {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }


        }

}
        private static String tagInfo(Element element, String info, int index)
        {
                return element.getElementsByTagName(info).item(index).getTextContent();
        }

    public static void searchMenu(String[] args) {

        //Hostel hostel = new Hostel();
    availableSearch(20140704, 20140705);
    //int start = 20130704;//Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
    //int end = 20140705; //Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
    //HostelSystem.search("San Franciso",20140704,20140705);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Just added code, the availableSearch function works inside the parser but not outside (searchMenu funciton)